# GCC produces call to sincos despite -fno-builtin-sincos flag

Tags: c, gcc

For my application (a numerical calculation), it's important that debug and release executables return the exact same results for the same inputs. I've been tracking down a new discrepancy between them, and found it to be the fault of GCC combining a `sin` and `cos` calculation into one call to `sincos`, with the resulting `sin` value differing from what a regular call to `sin` would return. Some googling tells me this can happen.

Very well, I resolve to not use `sincos`, or to not let the compiler use it. On godbolt, I provide the following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double d;
    scanf("%lf", &d);
    double sd = sin(d);
    double cd = cos(d);
    printf("%f, %f", sd, cd);
    return 0;
}
```

And the following flags `-O3 -fno-builtin-sincos`. This does not work, GCC still emits a call to `sincos`. If, however, I replace the flag with plain `-fno-builtin`, then GCC obeys and makes separate calls to `sin` and `cos`.

For completeness, I also tried `-fno-builtin-sincos -fno-builtin-sincosf -fno-builtin-sincosl`, no dice.

Is this a GCC bug?

Comment: By the way, why are you compiling a C program with `-std=c++11`? Stack overflow policy is not to tag a question with both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. You should narrow the question to one language.

Comment: Can you show a value for which `sin` and `sincos` return different values for the sine?

Comment: Since you tagged with C++, remember to use `g++` and not `gcc`.  The `gcc` is for the C language.

Comment: You might be able to work around this (at the expense of some performance) by declaring `d` `volatile`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Apologies, the application is C++ code but the problem shows up in C. I have fixed the tags and the flags mentioned in the question

Comment: Regarding specific values that demonstrate the problem, I have since lost my test setup, however I imagine that "bad" values are dependent on the `sincos` implementation. If you had an interest in reproducing the behavior you might not even be able to. For completeness sake I will mention that I saw the error on a CentOS 7 docker image running on Windows

Comment: @markalian: There at least two reasons for identifying values that reproduce the problem. One, the common part of `sin` and `cos` is the argument reduction. Both need to reduce large arguments to an interval supported by the approximating polynomials. `sincos` is typically implemented by performing that reduction and then calculating the polynomials separately. Separate `sin` and `cos` implementations typically work by performing the same reduction, so they should get the same results as `sincos`…

Comment: … If they do not, this is an oddity that should be reported to the implementor so they can investigate and perhaps reconsider the implementations. Two, because of the above, it is usual for `sincos` to provide different results than `sin` and `cos`, and this is suggestive of a misdiagnosed reason for your program producing different results between debug and release versions. Reproducing the problem in a controlled manner is important for diagnosis and correction.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I am sympathetic to your concerns. I set up some new test code in the hopes of printing to a file "bad" inputs, and have found a few. Moreover, I am lucky and it happens on godbolt as well (probably because I am using the system `gcc`/`glibc`. The following link provides a few numbers (at least some in the valid range, and all in what I'd call the "reasonable" range of -2pi to 2pi). https://godbolt.org/z/axT67z8MY

Comment: One other comment was about a misdiagnosis. The fix presented in the original answer results in identical results provided by the debug and release executables, so I am confident that it was the problem. I admit to not really knowing why I hadn't run into this problem earlier, but I'm ok with leaving that to the imagination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compile with `-fno-builtin-sin -fno-builtin-cos`.

`-fno-builtin-sincos` tells GCC not to treat `sincos` in source code as a known built-in function, but `sin` and `cos` are still known functions, so it is entitled to rely on their properties, namely that they compute a sine and a cosine which can be obtained by calling the library routine `sincos`.

Comment: I can confirm this works on the snippet above. Appreciate the answer